# How to write to JSON files in Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, vercel

I'm trying to write to a few JSON files in my Next.js/Vercel app, but I keep getting the following error when my project deploys to Vercel

```
Failed to compile.
./node_modules/chownr/chownr.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/chownr'
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/tar-fs/index.js
./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserFetcher.js
./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/Puppeteer.js
./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/initialize-node.js
./node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node.js
./node_modules/puppeteer/cjs-entry.js
./pages/index.js
./node_modules/extract-zip/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/vercel/path0/node_modules/extract-zip'
```

code which uses fs

```
fs.writeFile('./data/cases.json', 
    JSON.stringify(cases_to_write), (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('The file has been saved!', 'cases');
    });
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I can use fs in my app?

Comment: I don't think you can write on vercels servers. you have to use a database plugin or another service